# Can't change header logo in Magento?

Tags: magento, header

I have created my own theme for magento, and I am trying to edit the logo and am having difficulty.

I have created my own local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml file, and specified within the config the following:

```
<logo_src>images/Race-Ramps-logo-streaked-gradient.gif</logo_src>
```

I created a custom layout in the file as well. I can see the custom layout file in the CMS, but my changes to the logo do absolutely nothing. I have even tried changing the original core config.xml, it still stays the same.

On multiple websites, I have been told to go to System > Configuration > Design > Header, but I do not have the header option?

Help please!

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992714/future-proofing-a-magento-xml-override

Answer (score 4):

The value you're changing (mostly likely, hard to tell without more context) in the configuration file is the **default** value for a the logo_src System Config variable.  This is not want you want to do.

The people who've told to change the value in System -> Configuration -> Design -> Header are correct.  If you don't have a header options there it's eitehr because

1. The person who setup your admin account didn't give you access (ask them)
2. You have the wrong configuration scope set (look in the upper left hand corner for the scope selector)
3. Someone tried to customize your Magento store and accidentally killed the header configuration

If you're desperate you could always search through your codebase for calls to `getLogoSrc`

```
base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
default/iphone/template/page/html/header.phtml
default/modern/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

and replace them with a hard coded image.

Comment: I was using an older version (1.3.6 I believe). I reinstalled using 1.4 and the header option was there.

Thank you for the information though!

Answer (score 1):

1. Save image at the below location

   /magento/skin/frontend/default/default/images/your_image_name.png
2. Login to the admin section

> System > Configuration > General > Design > Header > Logo Image Src

-- Replace the **images/logo.gif**  to  **images/your_image_name.png**

Your default magneto front-end header logo will be changed to your custom logo.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to make my logo show (in Magento Community 1.9) after I placed the file in this directory: /skin/frontend/base/default/images/logo_YCZ.jpg