# Future-proofing a Magento XML override

Tags: xml, magento, overriding

I'm aware of the Magento best-practices pattern that says that if I want to modify one of Magento's core files, I should copy the file (and matching directory tree structure) from /app/code/core into /app/code/local and modify the copy so that it overrides the original. I need to do that with one of Magento's core XML files - I've modified the file, and I want to make sure that it doesn't get overwritten later when I upgrade Magento.

Right now, I have a modified version /app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml in place - I edited it to add in a specific page layout that I need for my site. Now I want to move my modification out of the core files. Do I recreate the entire XML file in /app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml, or do I only need to put my additions and changes into a local override file?

If it's the latter, can someone explain the structure of this to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not too much xml, you can pop it into app/etc/local.xml which is what I tend to do for custom layouts.

E.g.

```
<config>
  <global>
    <!-- ... -->
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <three_columns_test module="page" translate="label">
          <label>3 Columns Test</label>
          <template>page/3columns-test.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>page_three_columns_test</layout_handle>
        </three_columns_test>
        <new_homepage module="page" translate="label">
          <label>Homepage Layout</label>
          <template>page/homepage.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>page_homepage</layout_handle>
        </new_homepage>
      </layouts>
    </page>
    <!-- ... -->
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: I like Alans answer above, but my comfort level with his suggestion is not where it should be right now. I mighjt come back to that later.

For now, I'd like to give this suggestion a go. I am assuming this will not break any of the pages on which I have build content using my alternative page layout?

Comment: Aaron, would I simply copy the XML for my extra page (5 xml lines), or do I need to copy all the standard pages as well as my extra one ( duplicate the <page> <layouts> xml section)?

Comment: Just copy the stuff for your custom layouts and pop it between <page> tags inside <config><global> in local.xml

Comment: I would like to thank you both, but I cannot :-( I have updated my files using your quick fix method Aaron, and all is working fine. Thank you! What is the limit on XML in this app/etc/local.xml file - you mentioned "if it's not too much xml"? Just curious!

Comment: There's no limit as such to the amount you can put in local.xml, it's merely a maintainence / good practice thing. If you're putting so many layouts in local.xml, odds are it's an indication you should probably bite the bullet and make a custom module and follow Alan's approach.

Answer (score 11):

You can't exactly "override" a config.xml file that way.

Magento is made up of *code modules*.  `Mage_Page` is a single module.  A module contains a `config.xml` file, and numerous PHP files.

You can **override** certain types of **PHP** files in Magento by placing a replacement in

```
app/code/local/Package/Module/Path/To/File.php
```

That's because the __autoloader creates include statements that look like this

```
include('Package/Path/To/File.php')
```

and PHP will check each code pool for a file.

```
app/code/local
app/code/community
app/code/core
```

By placing a replacement file in local, Magento finds your file first and skips the core file.

You can't do the same thing with `config.xml`.  If you place a config.xml file at

```
app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc/config.xml
```

Magento will ignore it.  When you request a page in Magento, the system will create a list of active modules (from `app/modules/etc`), and then load each module's config.xml file.  You shouldn't be changing core config.xml files at all.

Based on your question, it sounds like you changed this `config.xml` file to add an additional `layout.xml` file.  If that's the case, then what you want to do is

1. Add a **new module** to magento.
2. In your new module's `config.xml` file, add the new layout node.

[This page](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config) (self link) covers the basic files you need to get a new Module in place.  However, instead of adding the observer stuff to `config.xml`, add your new layout node instead

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <my_unique_node_name>
                    <file>foo.xml</file>
                </my_unique_node_name>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: If I could thank you both (Green tick) I would! I have used Aarons method as I need this doing quick. I will endeavour to learn more on this subject, and your website articles are extremely useful so keep up the good work. Thank you!