# Magento: "overriding" core config.xml files via a local copy? Is this correct?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to rename some of the credit cards which appear on my Magento checkout (e.g. "Visa" becomes "Visa Debit/Credit").

To do this, I discovered you must edit the names as defined in `/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml`.

Not wanting to overwrite core files, I tried copying this file to `/app/code/local/Mage/Payment/etc/config.xml` and making my changes there, but it didn't work. From research, I gather than Magento doesn't autoload config files from local folders first?

I then discovered that you could change `app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml` and specify `<codePool>local</codePool>` instead of `<codePool>core</codePool>` under `<Mage_Payment>`. My changes made under the local folder would then work.

Is this the correct approach? Will changing the `codePool` of a core module have any repercussions? Is there some other way to "override" a core module's `config.xml`?

Comment: The <name> on config.xml represent each module, if config.xml are on local/Payment  the config is for local/Payment module, if on code/core/payment the config is for him. If you want change the name you must go to System -> Config -> Payment Method and change there

Comment: I took a look in there, but there is nowhere I can actually rename the credit cards. The names of the cards are actually being pulled from the core config.xml directly. For example if I change "Visa" to "Visa Credit" in the config.xml file, it works.

Comment: You can do like bixi say

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992714/future-proofing-a-magento-xml-override

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to create a new module under local : `Yourcompany_Payment`

In this module, define a minimalist etc/config.xml with the XML rewrite you need :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_Payment>
            <version>0.1.0.0</version>
        </Yourcompany_Payment>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <payment>
            <cc>
                <types>
                    <AE>
                        <code>AE</code>
                        <name>American Express</name>
                        <order>0</order>
                    </AE> [...]
```

And then in the `app/etc/modules` folder, add a new `Yourcompany_Payment.xml` (or Yourcompany_All.xml) with :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_Payment>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Payment/>
            </depends>
        </Yourcompany_Payment>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The depends node is vital because it will tell magento to load your XML after magento's one in order to your rewrite to work

Comment: That's great, Bixi. Thanks. Can you tell me what would happen if I simply edited Mage_All.xml and set `codePool` to `local` instead of `core`?

Comment: If you change the codePoll of Mage_Payment ? I think the whole module would be KO as magento would search the module's files in the app/local folder (where the module isn't) .. you can try, it won't do any bad, just revert it afterward (and clean cache). Don't forget to accept answer if it's ok to you for futur visitors ;)