# Modify Magento core text

Tags: magento

I would like to change the word 'Discover' to 'Diners Club' in the Magento checkout. They are selections for the saved credit card payment gateway.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If so, please update your question.

Comment: I have modified config.xml in Mage/Payment/etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Mage Payment etc config.xml

```
 <DI>
    <code>DI</code>
    <name>Discover</name>
    <order>30</order>
 </DI>
```

change name here clear cache and check.

Or in your app/etc/local.xml add this in your config node and change Discover to appropriate value

```
 </global>
    <payment>
        <cc>
            <types>
                <DI>
                    <code>DI</code>
                    <name>Discover</name>
                    <order>30</order>
                </DI>
            </types>
        </cc>
    </payment>
</global>
```

Comment: That works but it is changing the core. How can I do this without modifying the core?

Comment: I have copied the file to local/Mage/Payment/etc but it no longer works?

Comment: Well you need to define this in local.xml using same set of xml nodes

Comment: I have added explanation for local.xml related comment

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Wouldn't it still be loading the core config.xml?

Comment: I have noticed that if modify Mage_All.xml in app/etc/modules and under Payment instead of core put local then it works but again this is modifying the core?

Comment: did you clear cache.It should work as that's the standard Magento practice.paste what you did on your local.xml as you might have missed on some node.XML nodes would exactly match.

Comment: Its ok. I have found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250135/magento-overriding-core-config-xml-files-via-a-local-copy-is-this-correct